# ASP.NET: DataGridView not showing in website

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I have a problem with my datagridview. It works when the code is being executed in local but when i hosted it in the web server, the problem occurs.
The .aspx code is.

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvDocu" runat="server" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="White" 
                    AlternatingRowStyle-ForeColor="#000" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                    BackColor="#CCCCCC" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="3px" 
                    CellPadding="4" CellSpacing="2" ForeColor="Black" 
                    HeaderStyle-BackColor="#3AC0F2" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" 
                    RowStyle-BackColor="#A1DCF2" Width="250px">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="DocumentName" HeaderText="File Name" />
                        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownload" runat="server" 
                                    CommandArgument='<%# Eval("C_ID") %>' OnClick="DownloadFile" Text="Download"></asp:LinkButton>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <PagerStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    <RowStyle BackColor="White" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
                    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#808080" />
                    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
                    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#383838" />
                </asp:GridView>
```

The page load code is.

```
        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            BindGrid();
        }
        string uname = Session["ApplicantUsername"].ToString();
        username.Text = uname;
```

It is binded in the code behind with this code.

```
    private void BindGrid()
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT C_ID,DocumentName FROM CustomerRegistration WHERE ApplicantUsername = '" + username.Text + "'";
            cmd.Connection = cs;
            cs.Open();
            gvDocu.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            gvDocu.DataBind();
            cs.Close();
        }

    }
```

The downloading link code behind is.

```
 protected void DownloadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int id = int.Parse((sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument);
        byte[] bytes;
        string fileName, contentType;
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT DocumentName,DocumentContent,DocumentExt FROM CustomerRegistration WHERE C_ID=@C_ID";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C_ID", id);
            cmd.Connection = cs;
            cs.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                sdr.Read();
                bytes = (byte[])sdr["DocumentContent"];
                contentType = sdr["DocumentExt"].ToString();
                fileName = sdr["DocumentName"].ToString();
            }
            cs.Close();
        }

        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.ContentType = contentType;
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
        Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
```

I don't know the problem if it is in the web server or in my code. Thank you!

Comment: Connect to remotely and debug, chnge if (!This.IsPostBack) as (!Page.IsPostBack)

Comment: First of all you should decorate your code with proper Exception handling methods. Throw Exception when any exception occurs, it will help you to get details of the issue. You can find more details about exception on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173160.aspx

Comment: Can you please check your database connection properties and make sure you can connect to remote database.

Comment: I have already solved it. Thank you.